# React TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
        <div className="questions" id="questions">
          {Array(this.state.numQuestions).fill().map((number, questionIdx) => {
            return (
              <div> 
                <label>Question</label>
              <input type="text" onChange={this.handleQuestionChange.bind(questionIdx)}  />
              </div>);
          Array(4).fill().map((number, index) => {
          return <input type="text" key={index} onChange={this.handleAnswerChange.bind(questionIdx)}  />
          })}
          )
          })}
        </div>
```

I am getting a strange error for the line `<input type="text" onChange={this.handleQuestionChange.bind(questionIdx)}  />`

I'm not quite sure what the error means let alone how to fix it, here's the error information:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a `handleQuestionChange()` method on your component class?

Comment: I just accidentally misspelled it, it's all good now, thanks anyways!

Comment: In order to use `bind` the first parameter should be `this`, but that error means the function is undefined. should be like `this.handleQuestionChange.bind(this, questionIdx)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that `this.handleQuestionChange` is undefined, so you can't call `bind()` (or anything else) on it.

Check your object / functions and make sure it exists.

Comment: oh ok, will do!

Comment: Lol, I had the function spelled wrong. It's all good now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the arrow function, it's more elegant. 
Just simply define it like:

```js
const handleAnswerChange = (index) => {
  // do anything you like
  console.log(index)
  }
```

Then you don't have to bind your function. It's already worked.